# How to change the position of a button at a particular index

Tags: python, kivy

Please I would like to change the position of a button inside the list at any index to move in the x and y coordinate, but I don't seems to get it

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color

class LandingScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.buttons = [] #we will add references to all buttons here

        for x in range(4):
            self.buttons.append(Button(text='button ' + str(x+1), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5)))
            #make a reference to the button before adding it in
            self.add_widget(self.buttons[x])
 
         self.button[2] #change postion           

class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

Comment: The `BoxLayout` arranges the position of its children. If you want to set the positions of the children, perhaps you should use something like `FloatLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: The buttons are in a list I Want to change only the position of one button